# "He gives a present for me." is this sentence possible? (particularly, in grammar)

Tags: grammar

A. He gives a present to me.
B. He gives a present for me.

I know 'A' is correct. but I wonder 'B' is wrong? particularly in grammar.
In our country(non native english) everybody says 'B' is wrong.
so, do you(native speaker) think 'B' is really strange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second sentence does not sound totally natural, and it does not mean the same thing as the first sentence.

As a native speaker, I understand your second sentence to mean either:

> He gives a present [intended] for me [to someone else]
>
> He gives a present [on my behalf] [to someone else]

The phrase "*for me*" either modifies:

- "*present*," to describe the final intended recipient of the present.
- "*gives*," to indicate that he gives the present because I cannot (he does this *for me*)

Consider similar uses of *for*:

> I have two presents: one is *for Bob* and the other is *for Alice*. Because you will see Alice on her birthday, I will **give the present** *for Alice* **to you**.
>
> I cannot come to her birthday party. Can you give the present to her *for me*?

Although I can parse the sentence, your second sentence still seems strange because it doesn't say whom you give the present to, which is a necessary part of the act of giving.

Comment: I read it as 'he gives a present (to unspecified) on my behalf.. though I agree it's not a comfortable sentence.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's a slightly better way to read it; I've added it.

Comment: I intended 'for' as 'for my benefit or for my good'
if so
'He gives a present to me for my benefit' is this sentence possible?

Comment: @redkey88 That reading seems less likely than the two I've included in my answer, but might be possible. (Consider: "I didn't do it *for you*. I did it *for me*.") However, it still doesn't say who received the present. It only says that he gives a present [to someone], and that act of giving was done for my benefit. ("His job forced him to be far away from me, so, for me, he gave his boss his resignation." -- i.e., he quit his job for my benefit)